# bind datagrid to dataset

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

i have ben trying to assign dataset as source to grid. So, thisi is what i did:

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TEST",
                                               conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet d = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(d);
        grid2.DataSource = d;
        grid2.DataBind();
```

However, I am not able to get the result. The grid is not visible on the page. Can uplease let me know the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incomplete; however, this is how is done:

```
//notice how the connection is enclosed in a using block
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
        conn.Open();//don't forget to open the connection
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TEST",conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet d = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(d);
        grid2.DataSource = d;
        grid2.DataBind();
}
```

You don't need a DataAdapter, by the way. You can simply do this:

```
//notice how the connection is enclosed in a using block
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
        conn.Open();//don't forget to open the connection
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("TEST",conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        DataTable d = new DataTable();
        d.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        grid2.DataSource = d;
        grid2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: I have been doing the same thing from so much time but its not working somehow

Comment: @Nishanth: Then your proc is not returning any data.

Comment: yeah my proc is running good. To test it i just wrote a select * statement

Comment: @Nishanth: When you execute your code, does it throw any exceptions? have you looked at the connection string? Does it point to the right database, etc.? Again, code I posted is definitely correct. Put a break point and debug the app.

Comment: it doesnot throw any exception